# Blurry GDI+ text(DrawString)

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

The output of DrawString is getting very blurry for some reason. I'm looking for the same sharpness as the Windows menus, see attached image as reference.

[image]
The text of top window at is generated by the following code:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(m_DeviceContextHandle);

Gdiplus::FontFamily nameFontFamily(L"Segoe UI");
Gdiplus::Font       font(&nameFontFamily, 9);
Gdiplus::SolidBrush solidbrush(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 0));

graphics.SetCompositingQuality(Gdiplus::CompositingQuality::CompositingQualityAssumeLinear);
graphics.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingMode::SmoothingModeHighQuality);
graphics.SetPixelOffsetMode(Gdiplus::PixelOffsetMode::PixelOffsetModeHighQuality);
graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(Gdiplus::TextRenderingHint::TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit);
graphics.DrawString(L"File   Edit   Format   View   Help", -1, &font, Gdiplus::PointF(10, 10), &solidbrush);
```

Any ideas how I can sharpen the text?

**Edit:**

Here's the result when I draw to a bitmap instead of a window.
The first text is from the bitmap output, the last text is from when I draw to a window.
[image]

Code:

```
// Draw to bitmap.
Gdiplus::Bitmap b(100, 100);
Gdiplus::Graphics *g = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(&b);

// Draw text.
// ...


// Save bitmap.
CLSID pngClsid;
CLSIDFromString(L"{557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}", &pngClsid);

b.Save(L"C:\\my_path_here\\out.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
```

Any ideas? Incorrect settings of my window?

Comment: You probably have DPI settings at 125%, and you application is not DPI aware. Your window will be stretched and it doesn't look as sharp.

Comment: That's correct. Getting the result I am looking for when I changed my DPI settings from 125% to 100%. How can I override the DPI settings for my window?

Comment: You have to [make your app be DPI-aware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681.aspx), and then scale your drawing accordingly to the current resolution. Also see [High DPI desktop application development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/mt843498.aspx).

Comment: This issue has been solved by following the steps mentioned in the MSDN documents linked by Remy Lebeau, thanks.